# Cant access "Theme" and "Appearance" option in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, web

> Also i want to change header and footer style in my wordpress website. Actually i am not the actual admin, but admin has given me the authorization to work as an admin. Did he limited my access that i cant see all the features of wordpress dashboard?

Comment: Do you have FTP access?'

Answer (score 0):

If the in the wp-config.php file define(DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT, TRUE);
then you can not access the code part from admin section. To change the header of the website you must need the FTP detail to modify the files.

If you have anymore questions please let me know.